# C# DataGridView  вычисляемое значение в колонке

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне можно вычислить значение в колонке путем умножения (деления, сложения) значений 2х других колонок

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Просто если Вам не трудно приведите пример кода

Comment: Вам нужно такое поле только для отображения, или оно будет использоваться в каких-либо вычислениях?

Comment: @Gena_2007, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 1):

Следующий код вычисляет произведение первых двух ячеек из нулевой строки и помещает результат в третью:

```
var cellResult = dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[2];
var cellMul1   = dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0];
var cellMul2   = dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1];
cellResult.Value = (int)cellMul1.Value * (int)cellMul2.Value;
```

Comment: Заданное приведение является недопустимым

Comment: Я такой вариант рассматривал, только в цикле, потом результат нужно будет тоже использовать в вычислениях

Comment: а если приводить не к int, а к int? ?

cellResult.Value = (int?)cellMul1.Value * (int?)cellMul2.Value;

Comment: >> Заданное приведение является недопустимым

Значит, у тебя там не инты хранились. Сделай приведение типов.